# Swift Micro optimization: multiple if statements where fall-though will not occur vs if else if

Tags: swift, if-statement, optimization

If there is a difference which of these techniques is results in faster execution and why?

Using if statements allows calculating `numberOnePlusOne` only once.

```
func test(numberOne:Int, numberTwo:Int) {
    if numberOne == numberTwo {
      return
    }
    let numberOnePlusOne = numberOne + 1
    if numberOnePlusOne == numberTwo && numberOnePlusOne < numberTwo {
      return
    } else {
      return
    }
}
```

So if Using if else if is beneficial I would assume the benefit would be from the telling the compiler the blocks can't fall-though without an operation.

```
func test(numberOne:Int, numberTwo:Int) {
    if numberOne == numberTwo {
      return
    } else if numberOne + 1 == numberTwo && numberOne + 1 < numberTwo {
      return
    } else {
      return
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If there is a difference which of these techniques is results in faster execution and why?

If you consider that LLVM bytecode is an intermediate language, the translation of which results in either a machine-specific machine language (e.g. compilation to x86 or ARM machine code) or behaviour (interpretation) then the answer to this should be clear:

Some machines are faster at some things than others. One might be faster at branching while another might devote that branch prediction circuitry to extra cache memory, instead.

Basically, the problem with your question is that you're asking for synthetic benchmarks, assumably so you can write code tailored to that premature optimisation. Instead you should be writing your code to be easily maintained and using a profiler to identify the most significant bottlenecks. Optimise based on that, then profile again to ensure you got it right. Find the next bottleneck, rinse, repeat and lather. There are multiple benefits to this approach:

- Most importantly, you'll spend less time implementing the best optimisations; this is optimising your time.
- You won't be pushing more significant optimisations out of the realm of possibility with micro-optimisation guesswork. Some optimisations can prevent others...
- Your code will be much more legible.

I recommend you optimise like this per-system if possible. In this case, I highly doubt this is likely to be a significant bottleneck in any real code, and I have confidence that a quality compiler based on LLVM can optimise *both* of these to the same machine code... Consider that it can perform dead code analysis, *ahead of time*.

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely, absolutely on the wrong path. You are looking at micro optimisations. Micro optimisations sometimes save nanoseconds, but most of the time they don't. Real programmers look at real optimisations that save microseconds :-) Or sometimes make the difference between software being usable or not.

And you really, really need to read a book about Swift. What does your function actually do? On first sight, it seems it does nothing and can be just optimised away. On a closer look, if numberOne + 1 overflows then it will and must crash, because that's how the language is defined, unless numberOne == numberTwo. So any decent optimising Swift compiler will turn this into something like

```
if numberOne != numberTwo {
    check_overflow (numberOne + 1); 
}
```

And the first rule of optimisation is: If you didn't measure it, then don't optimise it. Because not measuring means you have no idea what you are doing, whether optimisation worked or not, and whether there was any need for optimisation.

A second rule for optimisation is this: Compiler engineers build optimisations into their compiler that help in real, useful code. They identify patterns of code that can be optimised. Nonsense code like yours won't fall into any of those patterns, so doesn't get optimised.

Comment: This code was never intended to be run. It's basic structure was derived from a I/O bound project I was working on. Due to curiosity about how the compiler would deal with both not a desire for micro optimization.